# What schema.org type should be used for content created by users for their buy or sell ads?

Tags: schema.org

In my website users can create their ads. Each ad has the following items that displays for public:

- ad title
- ad category (for example ad is about constructions or IT or …)
- ad type (for example ad is for sale or ask for buy or …)
- ad created date
- ad body
- ad owner contact info (but not for public, only logged in users)

Which Schema.org type should I use for this type of content? `Article` or other type?

Comment: Check this too: [What is a good microdata/schema for classfieds site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60022/what-is-a-good-microdata-schema-for-classfieds-site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they want to buy something: [`Demand`](https://schema.org/Demand)
If they want to sell something: [`Offer`](https://schema.org/Offer)

The actual thing they want to buy/sell would be a `Product` (or `Service`), specified by the [`itemOffered`](https://schema.org/itemOffered) property.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend "Article" as this refers to a news article or investigative report - certainly NOT an ad posted by people.

I much more would ask the user (poster) whether they are advertising a product or service (in case both is possible on your site). Depending on what they select I would then describe the data either as

[Service](https://schema.org/Service): https://schema.org/Service

or

[Product](https://schema.org/Product): https://schema.org/Product

Comment: because user creates the content, i can not set some properties for example brand, audience, color and ..
and for the items that i specified in the question , which properties do you suggest per type?

Comment: Well, what are they advertising for? Give two different possible examples - then I will give you a complete answer :) @Ali_Hr

Comment: As I haven't heard back from you - remember, some attributes are optional - the rest, make the user pick the correct attribute value via text field or dropdowns. That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

As Georg mentioned, definitely not the "Article" but this should be sufficient: https://schema.org/WPAdBlock.